# Recorrer con ngfor Map

Tags: angular

Quiero recorrer un map:

```
this.result = [ { "SMA": { "weight": 1, "override": 0, "finalWeight": 1 } } ]
```

y en mi html

```
<tr *ngFor="let wei of result ; index as key">
     <td>{{key}}</td>      => AQUI ME MUESTRA UN 0
     <td>{{wei}}</td>      => AQUI ME MUESTRA { "SMA": { "weight": 1, "override": 0, "finalWeight": 1} }    
</tr>
```

No puedo acceder a los valores de weight, override, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes acceder con notación de punto de esta manera:

```
<pre *ngFor="let data of result; index as i">
  {{ data | json }}
  
  <!-- Acceder a datos de SMA -->
  weight: {{data.SMA.weight}}
  override: {{data.SMA.override}}
  finalWeight: {{data.SMA.finalWeight}}

</pre>
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s58mxg?file=src/app/app.component.html)

## Actualización

Con la siguiente estructura:

```
  result2 = [
    { SMA: { weight: 1, override: 0, finalWeight: 1 } },
    { TEST: { weight: 2, override: 20, finalWeight: 222 } },
  ];
```

Puedes usar el pipe `keyvalue` para obtener la llave y el valor de manera dinámica. Para esto necesitas usar un segúndo `ngFor`:

```
<pre *ngFor="let data of result2; index as i">
  {{i}}
  <ng-container *ngFor="let key_value of data | keyvalue">
    Datos:{{key_value.key}}
    <!-- Acceder a datos de SMA -->
    weight: {{key_value.value.weight}}
    override: {{key_value.value.override}}
    finalWeight: {{key_value.value.finalWeight}}
  </ng-container>
</pre>
```

Te dejo [otro ejemplo funcional aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kaekrd?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Si tengo el sgte array no es válido   result = [
    { SMA: { weight: 1, override: 0, finalWeight: 1 } },
    { TEST: { weight: 2, override: 20, finalWeight: 222 } },
  ];

Comment: @sirdaiz Revisa mi edición.

Comment: He modificado a <ng-container *ngFor="let key_value of data; index as keyvalue"> y <td>{{key_value.key | json}}</td> pero no me sale nada, sin embargo al poner <td>{{key_value | json}}</td> veo todo esto { SMA: { weight: 1, override: 0, finalWeight: 1 } }

Comment: @sirdaiz Revisaste el segundo ejemplo?

Comment: estaba intentando hacerlo todo en un ngfor, vi tu ejemplo adjunto y veo que esta en 2 for,(pre y ng-container), lo hice asi y funcionó, gracias